# Show architecture in "Add/Remove Programs" entry for Python module

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer, distutils

I am creating an MSI for a Python package (which includes compiled extension modules) using the `bdist_msi` option to a `setup.py` based on `distutils`. How do I get the entry in the Windows "Add/Remove Programs" dialog to show the architecture for this module? The entry should look like:

```
Python 3.3 MyModule-1.1.0 (64-bit)
```

or

```
Python 3.3 MyModule-1.1.0
```

for the 64- or 32-bit versions of the package, respectively. How do other packages get this behavior?

I've looked at the `setup.py` for other packages that do show this behavior, but haven't been able to figure this out. I think that putting this in the `version` argument to `setup(...)` is incorrect, since that would affect the name of the generated installer (which already contains the architecture) as well as name of the `.egg-info` file that gets installed, which I don't see happening with other projects.

Comment: What are the "other packages that do show this behavior"?

Comment: On my system, I see this for Numpy, IPython, Matplotlib, PySide, and recent versions of Scipy.